# ServiceUrl "https://smba.trafficmanager.net/apac/" is not working

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I have a MS Teams bot. I have installed the bot for couple of users in tenant. Now when I'm starting conversation, for few users it is responding and few it is not.

I investigated further and found out that for users who are getting reply from bot, the serviceurl is "https://smba.trafficmanager.net/in/".

For users who are not getting reply from bot, the serviceurl is "https://smba.trafficmanager.net/apac/".

**Exception message**: Operation returned an invalid status code 'NotFound'

```
private async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
{
     var activity = await result as Activity;
     var reply = activity.CreateReply();
     reply.Text = "Hi there";
     await context.PostAsync(reply);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like it's possibly a [TrustServiceUrl Issue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-proactive-message?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp#avoiding-401-unauthorized-errors) (despite the 500 vs 401 error message).

You can fix it by adding all of your ServiceUrls to the list of trusted URLs:

```
private async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
{
     var activity = await result as Activity;
     var serviceUrl = activity.ServiceUrl;
     MicrosoftAppCredentials.TrustServiceUrl(serviceUrl);
     var reply = activity.CreateReply();
     reply.Text = "Hi there";
     await context.PostAsync(reply);
}
```

This should ensure that your bot "trusts" the ServiceUrl of any message that it receives.

Let me know how that goes. I'm 90% sure this is the issue, but it might not be.

---

[Here's a link](https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/master/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Connector/Authentication/MicrosoftAppCredentials.cs) to the library, if that helps. Otherwise, [browsing these issues](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues?q=label%3A%22Trust+Service+URL%22+is%3Aclosed) should help.

#### Note to others:

This "Trust Service URL Issue" doesn't apply to just Teams. This happens for lots of other URLs when trying to use Proactive messaging. Just replace `serviceUrl` with whatever is appropriate for your use case. And yes, if you're using multiple channels, you can add multiple URLs when using `MicrosoftAppCredentials.TrustServiceUrl()` by calling it multiple times.

Here's [the method definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.connector.authentication.microsoftappcredentials.trustserviceurl?view=botbuilder-dotnet-stable). Note: you can add expiration for this, as well.

[I've submitted a PR for this](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/pull/1262), which so far has resulted in [some updated docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-proactive-message?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp#avoiding-401-unauthorized-errors)

Comment: I have tried with adding serviceUrl into trusted urls. Here, it's not giving 401 unauthorized issue. Its saying "Operation returned an invalid status code 'NotFound'."

Comment: That's odd. Are all of your users within the [scope](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-CognitiveServices/issues/172) of the bot? Which operation is returning the "Not Found" exception? Are you able to share a link to your code?

Comment: @madhukarchaure04 Forgot to @.mention you so it notifies.